# Activation with Codeigniter send mail

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I want to send a mail to the user with the Registration Form I made with codeigniter. But I have a problem: The failed section that I printed on the screen comes in and I don't have mail in my mailbox. How Can I do this? Can you help me? In summary, I want to send an e-mail to the user using the Registration Form I did with Codeigniter and I did not.

**File Name: Member.php**

**My Codes**

```
if($insert){

            //Aktivasyon maili at

            $config = array(

                "protocol" => "smtp",
                "smtp_host" => "ssl://smtp.gmail.com",
                "smtp_port" => 465,
                "smtp_pass" => "****",
                "smtp_user" => "lolo12345shd@gmail.com",
                "starttls" => true,
                "charset" => "utf-8",
                "mailtype" => "html",
                "wordwrap" => true,
                "newline" => "\r\n",

            );
            $link =base_url("member/activation/$acitavtion_code");

            $message = "Merhabalar, {$this->input->post("full_name")}, <br> Üyeliğinizi aktifleşmesi için sadece bir adım kaldı
            Üyeliğiniz aktifleştirmek için <a href='$link'>Tıklayınız</a> ";

            $config = $this->load->library("email" , $config);

            $this->email->from("lolo12345shd@gmail.com", "lolo12345");
            $this->email->to($this->input->post("email"));
            $this->email->subject("Üyelik Aktivasyonu");
            $this->email->message($message);

           $send = $this->email->send();

            if($send){
                echo "succes";



            }else{

                echo "failed";

            }
```

Comment: My guess is you are probably on localhost? If your server isn't properly configured it wont work. Further you can see what error you are getting (usually) by enabling error reporting.

Comment: Yes I am using localhost, how to enable error notifications

Comment: Yea you have to configure your server properly for it all to work. There are already answers on here about how to do it just type localhost email configuration or localhost mail not sending or whatever.

Comment: please google it, how to send the email from localhost

Comment: How to use the search function?

Comment: @Alex, can you send me links to help?